# numpy.extract and numpy.any functions, is it possible to make it simpler way?

Tags: python, numpy

If there is any possibility to make this code simpler, I'd really appreciate it! I am trying to get rid of rows with zeros. The first column is date. If all other columns are zero, they have to be deleted. Number of columns varies.

```
import numpy as np

condition = [ np.any( list(x)[1:] ) for x in r]
r = np.extract( condition, r )
```

[`numpy.extract` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.extract.html)

Comment: seems simple enough to me. what are you not happy about?

Comment: just felt that for ndarray had to be a better way, conversion to list and then list comprehension looked weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the list comprehension and instead use fancy indexing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import datetime
r=np.array([(datetime.date(2000,1,1),0,1),
            (datetime.date(2000,1,1),1,1),
            (datetime.date(2000,1,1),1,0),
            (datetime.date(2000,1,1),0,0),                        
            ])
r=r[r[:,1:].any(axis=1)]
print(r)
# [[2000-01-01 0 1]
#  [2000-01-01 1 1]
#  [2000-01-01 1 0]
```

if r is an ndarray, then
r[:,1:] is a view with the first column removed.
r[:,1:].any(axis=1) is a boolean array, which you can then use as a "fancy index"

Comment: Ugh, I can't read this. Please format as "Code Sample".  Edit your text, select the code, and click on the button that looks like "101/010".

Comment: This is a promising answer, but I don't think it is quite correct yet.  He wants rows compressed if they are *all* zeroes, not if any single value is zero.

Comment: absolutely what I needed, thanks a lot, should have known ndarray indexing better!